# Sending data between two Activities using Explicit Intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two Activities - Activity A, and Activity B. The user is presented with Activity A on opening the app.

When you click a button on Activity A, it opens Activity B.

In Activity B, the user is prompted to add some text into an EditText field, which is stored in a TextView object.

When you click a button on Activity B, it redirects you to Activity A, and passes the data stored in the TextView object to Activity A to display on the screen.

My assumed logic:

Activity A constructs a new Intent and passes in Activity B.

Activity A calls startActivityForResult(intent).

Activity B then calls getIntent(), but does nothing with it, because there is nothing required(?)

In onClick() method, Activity B creates a new Intent, passing in Activity A. Activity B puts its results in the new Intent (i.e. using intent.putExtra() )

onActivityResult() in Activity A is called.

I'm wondering, if this is the right logic?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're doing things exactly how you're expected to. It may seem a little odd to be passing data through intents, but that's how Android was designed. Have in mind that activities may live in different processes, so the system serializes and deserializes the data in order to perform inter-process communication. The intent mechanism is the standard way of exchanging information across them and that's why intents only hold primitive data, Parcelables and Serializables. That being said, a piece of data exchanged by an intent is never the same instance on both sides, but an actual copy of the original data.

Comment: Thanks Flavio - I guess I just wasn't understanding why Activity B has to get the Intent, but then do nothing with it, and create a new one?

Comment: The Intent doesn't hold only shared information. It holds things that allow the system to know what is the target activity. It is fine to get an empty intent. You may not need to read any info from it, but the system had to in order to resolve the activity you're calling.

Comment: The request code is used in `onActivityResult()` to handle activity calls differently. Let's say you also have Activity C that returns results. How would you tell apart a result that comes from B or C? you can just test the request code in `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: OK, perfect - now I understand :) Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: "a piece of data exchanged by an intent is never the same instance" — this is blatantly wrong. It is almost always the same instance, because Bundle internally avoids performing serialize/deserialize cycle as long as it has references to original objects in memory.

Comment: @user1643723 What do you have to back this statement, my friend? You are blatantly wrong. I wrote a minimal test app so that you can run and see it for yourself: http://pastebin.com/UZu78YaF

Comment: So it seems, I was blatantly wrong myself. Just re-checked, and indeed, nothing besides LocalBroadcastManager (which simply never passes anything between processes) exhibits the behavior I described in my comment above.

Comment: @FlávioFaria you are wrong. The result intent is NOT supposed to have any reference to the activity that need to receive the result. It is perfectly possible to use that mechanism with a caller activity from another application that someone else developed.

Comment: @DanieleSegato When I said _"It holds things that allow the system to know what is the target activity"_, I meant an Intent that is used to start a new Activity, not returning a result to the caller one. _Target activity_ is a common term to refer to activities resolved by the `IntentResolver`, in this case, being called by another one, not the other way around.

Comment: @FlávioFaria I know :-) but the way you wrote it down can be misinterpreted by a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Your logic looks fine as mentioned by  Flavio. Just wanted to add that you don't have to call getIntent() in Activity B if you are not expecting anything from intent. You can avoid that line.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not how you are supposed to do it.

When using `startActivityForResult()` the activity being called (B in your example) has to use: `setResult()` before `finish()`. This is the way it gives a result to the calling activity.

From activity B there's no need to call `getIntent()` unless you need some parameter or to check if you've been called for result.

Let's make an example: `FriendsActivity` is an activity meant to manage friends, it usually show the current friends list and allow adding more.

From some place of your app you need the user to select a Friend for some action, so you have a button: *choose friend*, which open `FriendsActivity` with `ACTION_PICK` and `startActivityForResult()`.

All of that looks like this:

```
Intent pickFriendIntent = new Intent(this, FriendsActivity.class);
pickFriendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
startActivityForResult(pickFriendIntent, REQUEST_PICK_FRIEND);
```

The `REQUEST_PICK_FRIEND` is a constant `int` defined in the caller activity (useful if you have more then one type of request with result).

From `FriendsActivity`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // boolean flag to know if we are requested to pick or not
    mPickMode = getIntent() != null && Intent.ACTION_PICK.equals(getIntent().getAction());
    // etc...
}
```

The flag let us modify the behavior of our activity to pick a friend.

For example when clicking a friend, instead of going to his profile (or whatever action was used before) we are supposed to return the friend information and finish the activity:

```
public void onFriendClicked(Friend theFriend) {
    if (mPickMode) {
        Intent resultData = new Intent();
        // assuming Friend is Parcelable, if not just pass an ID or something
        // it's usually best to handle this with a custom Uri actually
        resultData.putExtra("friendParcelable", theFriend);
        // here we set the result for the calling activity
        setResult(RESULT_FRIEND_PICKED, resultData);
        // and then we finish this one
        finish();
    } else { ... }
}
```

The `RESULT_FRIEND_PICKED` is an `int` constant, usually public. It tells which kind of result happened to the parent activity, you can have more then one, to your needs. It's actually a good idea also to make public constants for extras, like `"friendParcelable"` in the above example.

When the `FriendsActivity` finish the caller get the callback:

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, 
            int resultCode, 
            Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_FRIEND) {
        if (resultCode == FriendsActivity.RESULT_FRIEND_PICKED) {
            Friend pickedFriend = data.getParcelableExtra("friendParcelable");
            // do whatever you want with that information
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // the FriendsActivity terminated without calling setResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that it is not mandatory to call `finish()` right after `setResult()`. If you call `setResult()` and then let the user click back it will still provide the result back. However if after the call to `setResult()` the activity is destroyed and re-created (ex. device rotation) you'll have to call `setResult()` again.